# spring is it advisable to make all domain classes prototype

Tags: spring

In most cases only service classes are managed by spring and are singletons. In some situations, domain code needs injection which won't work unless its managed by spring. That being said, it is advisable and non performance intensive to have all your domain classes as @bean with scope as prototype and anytime you want to do

```
Person p = new Person();
```

just do

```
Person p = ctx.getBean("person");
```

Any help on the pros and cons would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking which one is better? question is a little unclear.

Comment: *In some situations, domain code needs injection*. If I were you I'd try to get rid of these situations.

Comment: I am trying to find out if it is ok to create prototype bean of all domain classes

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously more overhead in obtaining a prototype bean than simply instantiating directly via the new keyword (any dependency injection, lifecycle callbacks, etc. performed by the Spring IoC container).  While likely not significant for a single instantiation, if you performed this in a loop, you could see performance issues.

If, however, you need any singleton beans (typically services) or resources (such as a DataSource), then you will prefer to use the prototype bean.  Any additional dependencies will be wired in automatically.

Apart from performance considerations, your choice may also depend on your design.  If you follow a "traditional" architecture with a service tier and data access objects that perist domain objects, then everything from a Spring point of view is generally stateless.  Your services and data access objects are singletons using domain objects that are POJO's.  Here you will rarely need a prototype bean.

If on the other hand you follow a more object-oriented approach where an object has a stateless factory (to allow instances to be fetched or created) and the object is then able to persist itself (say with a 'save' method), then nearly all your domain objects may be prototype beans.

As in nearly all decisions, there will be trade-offs and no one right answer.